# C# Error CS1513

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I don't understand what is causing a CS1513 error. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameStarted : MonoBehaviour {

void GameStartMsg()
{
    Debug.Log("Game started!");
}
```

That's all I see:

[image]

Comment: Thats all i see... https://gyazo.com/1142bb380163f5ba3321c1d644709732

Comment: Your error description in the screenshot shows '} expected'. Your compiler told you the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please attempt to answer questions yourself.

Googling 'error CS1513' lead to this page as the first result - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ht1k63%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Grant Winney's comment is correct, missing brace.

Comment: Oke...I get it..But what i need to do?  Just to add } ?

Comment: The error description shows line 9 - so your problem is on line 9. The description shows '} missing', so you're missing a brace on line 9.

Comment: @AleksejJovanovic - For every `{` there must be a `}`. -- Maybe you should start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67ef8sbd.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong is you need to add a curly brace to the end of your code at line nine. That will get rid of the error. CS1513 error = missing closing bracket.